# .htaccess to rewrite migrated Wordpress site

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, wordpress, 301-redirect

I've moved my Wordpress from one domain to another, and I want the use .htaccess 301 redirects to redirect posts on the old domain to posts on the new domain.

My webhost suggested I try the following:

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?steve\.doig\.com\.au/wordpress/$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.superlogical.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works only for the /wordpress folder, but not for any of the category pages or posts.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?steve\.doig\.com\.au/wordpress/$ [NC]` is setting a condition on the rewrite process. Basically it only works on urls finished with `/wordpress/`. Try commenting that line (if you only have the Wordpress installation running, it will redirect everything).

Comment: Brilliant, that fixed it.